# Use plus-equal to modify multiple variables?

Tags: python

When using the += operator in Python you can do

```
>>>a=42
>>>a+=1
>>>a
43
```

Now let's say I have

```
>>>a=1
>>>b=1
>>>c=1
```

and want to do

```
>>>a, b, c += 1, 2, 3
```

to be shorthand for

```
>>>a+=1
>>>b+=2
>>>c+=3
```

Right now my code looks like

```
rt, gt, bt = 0,0,0
for yi in range(self.ysize):
    for xi in range(self.xsize):
        ri, gi, bi, = self.pix[xi, yi][:3]
        rt += ri
        gt += gi
        bt += bi
num_pixels = self.xsize*self.ysize
r = rt/num_pixels
g = gt/num_pixels
b = bt/num_pixels
return int(r), int(g), int(b)
```

I'd like to be able to set the three values in one line so that the code is cleaner.

Is there a way to use += for this?

Is there a way to do this that is short and concise (not defining a function to do it for me)

Is there a better way to loop through a 2-d array and average the tuples?

Comment: Is that really going to make your code cleaner?

Comment: I feel like rt, gt, bt += ri, gi, bi is cleaner. If not cleaner then shorter with similar readability

Comment: You could define your own sequence container type (that was similar to `tuple`s and `list`s) and define its [`iadd()` (or `__iadd__()`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.iadd) method to do what you want (but you can't change how it works for the built-in container classes).

Comment: If `pix` is a picture (I'm guessing), then why would each pixel not be representable as an array with three values? You should encode it such that you can do `t += self.pix[:,xi,yi]`. For example make `pix` a 3D numpy array.

Answer (score 4):

the short answer is no. 
 augmented assignment cannot be used with tuple unpacking

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy` to get this behavior:

```
x = np.arange(5)
x += np.arange(5)
print x

array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Packing / unpacking steps:

```
vals = np.array([a, b, c])
vals += 1, 2, 3
# now you can use vals[0] for a, vals[1] for b and vals[2] for c
# but if you want to keep using a,b,c variable names:
a,b,c = vals
```

Comment: OP wants multiple variables, a numpy array is still a single entity. so there would need to be an unpacking step.

Comment: np arrays do ok for a homogeneous group, it wouldn;t easily extend to a mix of ints, floats, strings, tuples, lists, etc

Comment: No, it will work for any thing that has addition defined: `np.array([1, 2.0, "three", np.array([4,5])], dtype=object) + np.array([6,7.0,"eight",np.array([9,10])], dtype=object)`
==> `array([7, 9.0, 'threeeight', array([13, 15])], dtype=object)`

Comment: won't perform properly since there is no inherent binding of a, b, c  to val.  for instance what if the OP then wanted to increment `a, b, d` ?  or place  `a = 999` between the packing and the unpacking. the former requires numerous nparrays and never-ending bookkeeping, and the latter fails on the 'unpacking.' since `var` is unaware. your solution is dangerous.